# NFC Encrypt Data

Tags: android, encryption, key, nfc

Thanks for the help in the forum, I am able to read and write tag using "TNF_MIME_MEDIA". Now I want to encrypt my data so no one can see it. I searched the web and found no result. Does anyone use the encryption feature? Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Some example code to show what you are trying to do would perhaps be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use it to write arbitrary data, why not just encrypt it with AES or something ?

Comment: That's what I do, though I think I should probably define the Type Name Format as TNF_EXTERNAL, i.e. 'application specific', since in doing so, I don't think I am following the defined standards.